# ScalaTest: Issues with Singleton Object re-initialization

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am testing a parser I have written in Scala using ScalaTest. The parser handles one file at a time and it has a singleton object like following:

```
class Parser{...}
object Resolver {...}
```

The test case I have written is somewhat like this

```
   describe("Syntax:") {
    val dir = new File("tests\\syntax");
    val files = dir.listFiles.filter(
                    f => """.*\.chalice$""".r.findFirstIn(f.getName).isDefined);

    for(inputFile <- files) {
      val parser = new Parser();
      val c = Resolver.getClass.getConstructor();
      c.setAccessible(true);
      c.newInstance();

      val iserror = errortest(inputFile)
      val result = invokeparser(parser,inputFile.getAbsolutePath) //local method
      it(inputFile.getName + (if (iserror)" ERR" else " NOERR") ){
      if (!iserror) result should be (ResolverSuccess()) 
        else if(result.isInstanceOf[ResolverError]) assert(true)
      }
    }
  }
```

Now at each iteration the side effects of previous iterations inside the singleton object Resolver are not cleaned up.

Is there any way to specify to scalatest module to re-initialize the singleton objects?

**Update**: Using Daniel's suggestion, I have updated the code, also added more details.

**Update**: Apparently it is the Parser which is doing something fishy. At subsequent calls it doesn't discard the previous AST. strange. since this is off topic, I would dig more and probably use a separate thread for the discussion, thanks all for answering

**Final Update**: The issue was with a singleton object other than Resolver, it was in some other file so I had somehow missed it. I was able to solve this using Daniel Spiewak's reply. It is dirty way to do things but its also the only thing, given my circumstances and also given the fact I am writing a test code, which is not going into production use.

Comment: Is there a clean-up method inside `R`, or do you expect it to be re-created?

Comment: there is no cleanup method in R and I can't change the code.

Can you recreate singleton objects in Scala?

Comment: Nope. They're strictly singletons. Initialized on-demand (as determined by the JVM's class-loading) and thereafter eternal. They can have mutable internal state, of course, as with any Scala classes.

Comment: Your change wouldn't work assuming Parser is hard-coded to refer to the regular Resolver singleton instance. You're making a new instance of it here using the sneaky trick that Daniel suggested (then suggested you never use). What you need to do if Parser is really designed this way with a hard-coded reference to Resolver, which maintains state (not a very testable design), is load Resolver and Parser with a custom class loader for each test. I'll post that in a reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the language spec, no, there is no way to recreate singleton objects.  However, it *is* possible to reflectively invoke the constructor of a singleton, which overwrites the internal `MODULE$` field which contains the actual singleton value:

```
object Test

Test.hashCode    // => e.g. 779942019

val c = Test.getClass.getConstructor()
c.setAccessible(true)
c.newInstance()

Test.hashCode    // => e.g. 1806030550
```

Now that I've shared the evil secret with you, let me caution you never, *ever* to do this.  I would try very very hard to adjust the code, rather than playing sneaky tricks like this one.  However, if things are as you say, and you really do have no other option, this is at least something.

Comment: The re-initialization of singleton object this way works but my problem still persists. I don't know how.

Basically if I test each inputfile individually it works fine but if I test them together I get error. If I change the order I get an error then too (with error messages related to previous test case!).  I suspected that may be reason because singleton object has side effects from previous iterations.

Comment: Tried, got this... java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.whatever.SingletonObject$.<init>()

Comment: I had to change the above of @daniel-spiewak example to
`val c = Test.getClass.getDeclaredConstructor()`

Answer (score 4):

ScalaTest has several ways to let you reinitialize things between tests. However, this particular question is tough to answer without knowing more. The main question would be, what does it take to reinitialize the singleton object? If the singleton object can't be reinitialized without instantiating a new singleton object, then you'd need to make sure each test loaded the singleton object anew, which would require using custom class loaders. I find it hard to believe someone would design something that way, though. Can you update your question with more details like that? I'll take a look again later and see if the extra details makes the answer more obvious.

ScalaTest has a runpath that loads classes anew for each run, but not a testpath. So you'll have to roll your own. The real problem here is that someone has designed this in a way that it is not easily tested. I would look at loading Resolver and Parser with a URLClassLoader inside each test. That way you'd get a new Resolver each test.

You'll need to take Parser & Resolver off of the classpath and off of the runpath. Put them into a directory of their own. Then create a URLClassLoader for each test that points to that directory. Then call findClass("Parser") on that class loader to get it. I'm assuming Parser refers to Resolver, and in that case the JVM will go back to the class loader that loaded Parser to get Resolver, which is your URLClassLoader. Do a newInstance on the Parser to get the instance. That should solve your problem, because you'll get a new Resolver singleton object for each test.

Comment: creating a new Parser doesn't reinitialize the singleton object and parser object creation is inside the loop. (check updated code)

the code was made to accept a single input file in one execution trace.

Answer (score 0):

No answer, but I do have a simple example of where you might want to reset the singleton object in order to test the singleton construction in multiple, potential situations.  Consider something stupid like the following code.  You may want to write tests that validates that an exception is thrown when the environment isn't setup correctly and also write a test validates that an exception does not occur when the environment is not setup correctly.  I know, I know everyone says, "Provide a default when the environment isn't setup correctly." but I DO NOT want to do this; it would cause issues because there would be no notification that you're using the wrong system.

```
object RequiredProperties extends Enumeration {
  type RequiredProperties = String

  private def getRequiredEnvProp(propName: String) = {
    sys.env.get(propName) match {
      case None => throw new RuntimeException(s"$propName is required but not found in the environment.")
      case Some(x) => x
    }
  }

  val ENVIRONMENT: String = getRequiredEnvProp("ENVIRONMENT")
}
```

Usage:

```
Init(RequiredProperties.ENVIRONMENT)
```

If I provided a default then the user would never know that it wasn't set and defaulted to the dev environment.  Or something along these lines.